# Android intent to string giving incorrect value

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hey all i will try to keep this short and concise

I am developing an android application, and am struggling with passing a users, username back to the database

Username is passed through intent from previous activity, have displayed it in a textview to verify it displays the correct username, which it does on screen, yet it keeps posting "currentuser" to the database

```
    UserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UserName);
    UserName.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("CurrentUser"));
    final String LoggedInUser = (getIntent().getStringExtra("CurrentUser"));
    UserName.setText(LoggedInUser);
```

Then when it comes to posting in to the db this line should retreive the value

```
    UserName.getText().toString(),
```

Rest of the values are going through to the database fine, user input integers, for some reason the username keeps going through as

"Currentuser"

Any ideas on what i have done wrong?

Thank you

```
   intent.putExtra("CurrentUser", LoggedInUser);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: where is your putExtra() code?

Comment: Are you sure that you added the correct value to the intent?

Comment: Added the put extra code to the op, yes im sure as the correct username is displayed on screen in the textview, but not passed to the database

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that no where else in your code you put an extra into the intent with the same key? The keys are associated with a map and if 2 items share the same key it will only return the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

From previous activity :

```
private void YourMethodName(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("savedUser", savedUser);
        Log.e("username", "--->>" + savedUser);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Now , on next activity class `onCreate()` method,

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
String userName = extras.getStringExtra("savedUser");
```

than use it, etUsername is EditText,

```
etUsername.setText(userName);
```

Comment: Nope, this is pretty much what i have done. If i login as user "x", the intent passes the data through and says "welcome user x". I can see that on screen, when it comes to going to string and passing it to the database, All it passes through is "currentuser"

Comment: when you are getting that data, that is "X" at that time insert into database.

Comment: The original data comes from an edit text where the user enters their username. This is the same username textview that is in the original code posted. This is displayed on screen so i can see that the username is passed through, as the logged in user changes so does the displayed username. The issue is that his username is not posted in to the database, rather "currentuser" is. Thank you

Comment: i got that, thing is when you get username correctly than why dont you insert that in database at that time ? is there any query issue ?

Comment: It does, it inserts it along with 3 other edit texts. the edit texts go in fine. The username just inputs "currentuser". When it should display the username. The same textview that displays the username correctly on screen, when i do textview.getstring...... and pass it through it just says "currentuser"

Comment: Can you post your database insert code? It sounds like that might be suspect.

Comment: databases.open();
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        databases.insert(TableConstants.TABLE_LoginDetails, ColumnConstants.COLUMN_Name, cv);
        databases.close();

Comment: have posted demo for insert method @Nick

Comment: is this answer helped ?@uwotm8

Answer (score 0):

Okay fixed, i made a typo in the php. Instead of "$value" i posted 'value' which is why it kept posting currentuser

Thanks for the help everyone